# Python global variables across modules

Tags: python

Consider this module `foo`:

```py
var = 10

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import bar
    bar.call()

    print(var)
```

module `bar` looks like this:

```py
def call():
    import foo
    foo.var = 42
```

When I did `python foo.py`, I got `10` as output whereas I expected the output to be `42`.

I then printed `id` of `var` at both places. i.e.

in `bar`

```py
def call():
    import foo
    foo.var = 42
    print(id(foo.var))
```

in `foo`

```py
var = 10

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import bar
    bar.call()

    print(var)
    print(id(var))
```

And I got different identifiers:

```
4560760400
10
4560759376
```

This means that python created two separate copies of `var`. What is going on here? and what is the correct way of accomplishing this?

(I know globals are bad. I am not using them in production code)

Comment: Note that `id(var)` prints the id of the value, not of the variable. Variables have no id in Python!

Comment: The module in which you originally set `var = 10` is obviously not named `foo` - the `__name__ == '__main__'` check would not have passed in that case!  `import __main__` would have retrieved the existing module object, `import foo` creates another module object from the same source code.

Comment: @jasonharper Ah. that makes sense. Do you want to write that as a solution? I can accept that afterwards.

Comment: As an aside, objects have ID's, **not variables**

Comment: Also `10` and `42` being two instances of immutable `int` would always have different `id`. Sometime references to same values of immutable objects can (but don't have to) refer to the same object (`id`), but two objects (different immutable values) cannot have the same `id`.